# What does context.get('active_ids', []) mean? Why do we use it?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

The following code is from `export_stockinfo_xls` in Odoo 10. I want to know what mean `context.get('active_ids', [])` and what is the returned value. Why do we use `[]` in that expression?

```
@api.multi
def export_xls(self):
    context = self._context
    datas = {'ids': context.get('active_ids', [])} # what mean this and what return

    datas['model'] = 'product.product'
    datas['form'] = self.read()[0]

    for field in datas['form'].keys():
        if isinstance(datas['form'][field], tuple):
            datas['form'][field] = datas['form'][field][0]
    if context.get('xls_export'):
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'report_name': 'export_stockinfo_xls.stock_report_xls.xlsx',
            'datas': datas,
            'name': 'Current Stock'
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are in a tree view `context.get('active_ids', [])` returns a list of checked elements ids. If you are in a form view it returns the id of the item that you see on the screen. 
If there is no element id it returns an empty list ([]). 
I hope this help you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "tree view" and "form view"?

Answer (score 2):

the method `dict.get` is used to fetch a value from a dictionary. It has an additional parameter that returns a default value from a dict.

**dict.get Demo:**

```
dictionary = {"message": "Hello, World!"}
print(dictionary.get("message", ""))
print(dictionary.get("message_1111", "No Value"))   #Note: "message_1111" not in dictionary.
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, World!
No Value
```

**[MoreInfo](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get)**

*In your case.*

```
context.get('active_ids', [])
```

if `'active_ids'` is not in context returns an empty list.